# TemplatedParent was not set to a child of UserControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding, user-controls

In my project, I have a Usercontrol which contains two child controls say a textbox and a button. A Common Style was written in App.xaml for Textbox. So this style will apply for that usercontrol's Textbox and in tat textbox when i tried to get the TemplatedParent it was null. How do i get the Usercontrol from the Textbox, so that the properties in the Usercontrol can be get in the textbox style.

Answer (score 0):

`TemplatedParent` can be used within `ControlTemplate`.

For Style you need to use `RelativeSource` with mode set to `FindAncestor` and `AncestorType` set to `UserControl`.

Suppose you want to set `Text` to `Name of UserControl` from `TextBox Style`, you can do this way:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
   <Setter Property="Text"
           Value="{Binding Path=Name,
                           RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                   AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: your code will works fine for default userControl's properties but while go for my custom usercontrol, its not working.  `<Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding MyProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:UserControl1}}" />
        </Style>`

Comment: No it will work for that too. Post relevant code. It will work in case `UserControl` lies in parent Visual tree of TextBox.

Comment: As per the Visual Tree it will works but its not working.. that's the problem.

Comment: Ideally it should. If not than i suspect there is some problem in your code. Please post it here.

Comment: nothing more code to post here.. I have a `Usercontrol` named UserControl1 and `MyProperty` is a dependencyproperty which is in that `UserControl`type of string. This property to be accessed in the above posted binding.

Comment: And TextBox is inside UserControl?

Comment: This works for me. Make sure style is not getting override somewhere else under your Resource section.